# EmberJS: replaceWith & link-to change slash in url to %2F

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-encoding

In my ember app I need to use dynamic segments which may contain "/".

```
  this.route('lecture',  {path: '/:lecture_url'});
```

where :lecture_url can be string like 'new-article' or 'lectures/article'

If I type

```
localhost:4200/lectures/article
```

route resolver detects model and call replaceWith but the URL is changed to:

```
localhost:4200/lectures%2Farticle
```

Also, then I try to create link like

```
{{#link-to 'lecture' lecture.url}}smth{{/link-to}}
```

the href of link contains lectures%2Farticle too.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: dynamic url `:lecture_url` value cant be `lectures/article`. that means You may need to introduce one more dynamic segment or create a nested route.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method that you can use to solve this but I want to note something based on you code I can't really tell if lecture is contained in another route. This method uses the wildcard to allow `/` in the url. The issue is that this is meant to catch all that is entered past the root. So the code looks like:

```
this.route('lecture', { path: '/*path' });
```

so if this was placed the route this works correctly. but if we have:

```
this.route('lecture', { path: '/*path' });
this.route('folder', { path: '/folder' });
```

now we have a problem because if we type `/folder` in url we will now fall into the 'folder' route, not the lecture route but if we have

```
{{#link-to 'lecture' 'folder'}}Lecture:folder{{/link-to}}
```

we will end up on the correct lecture route but the url will be /folder so if the user comes back to this url they will go to the folder route instead of the lecture route.

TLDR;

use the wildcard format '/*path' but be careful of overlapping other routes.
[Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ffdf369aec1dbaaf3733f245cad11fd2/65cc990e760a6ee03a9abfa79f95ca7c9de49310?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)